# How to vertically center text inside a div in IE?

Tags: html, css, centering

I've seen this asked many times, none of the solutions are working for me.  As you can see in the Fiddle this is working exactly how I want it to in Chrome, but in IE the text is stuck at the top of the box, instead of in the middle. **If you run it in IE browser and Chrome side by side you'll see what I mean.** I want it in the middle exactly, using margin:auto; works perfectly in chrome, but in IE it doesn't.  I'm not sure of a fix that will move the paragraph down so it is aligned in the middle both vertically and horizontally.

```
<section class="info"> 
<p class="infofont">Size: Large<br><br>
100% Cotton<br><br>
Excellent Condition!
</p>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
.info{
display:flex;
width:325px;
margin:auto;    
}

.infofont{
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fmu8g38h/

Comment: Your fiddle is different, it has 500px height set on .info. Without that it won't work in any browser. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for which properties needs to be set for vertical alignment. Some browsers might need old syntax.

Answer (score 2):

try this instead:

```
.info{
    display:flex;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;   
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position:absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k1cbjvj7/1/

Answer (score 1):

margin:auto is used to align the texts horizontally.

to align in center the top portion must be aligned seperately

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write `flex-direction: row / column; align-items: center; justify-content: center;` for when `display` is `flex` and inside content will be `vertically` and `horizontally` center and you should remove `margin: auto;` from `.infofont` `class`.

> Below is update your CSS code.

```
.info{
    border: 1px solid black;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 325px;
    margin:auto auto;   
    height: 500px;  
}

.infofont{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
```

> Check the snipped

```css
.info{
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
 display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
 width:325px;
 margin:auto auto; 
  height:500px; 
}

.infofont{
  color: green;
  font-size: 16px;
 font-weight:bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0;
 text-align:center;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before{
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<section class="info"> 
<p class="infofont">Size: Large<br><br>
100% Cotton<br><br>
Excellent Condition!
</p>
 
</section>
```

> Note: I test this code only IE11, Chrome and Safari.